# ui-router's state params in data object

Tags: angularjs

I am using ui-router's state data to decide what page title to display on the page. I have a specific scenario where one state might have 2 different page titles because it is shared.

Say I have page titles 'Directors' and 'HR'. These are parameters passed into the state by `$state.go('main.employees', { pageType: 'HR' });`

How can I possibly get data to return params.pageType like `data: { pageTitle: this.params.pageType }`. Is there a way to get params in data?

```
.state('main.employees', {
    url: '/employees',
    params: {
        pageType: null
    },
    views: {
        'content': {
            templateUrl: 'app/employees/employees.html',
            controller: 'employeesCtrl as vm'
        }
    },
    data: {
        pageTitle: this.params.pageType    //<-- I have problem here
    }
})
```

I have to use params.pageType only in this specific case because other states do not have this param. I am relying on `$state.$current.data.pageTitle` to display it.

I've also tried this but then when calling this with `$state.$current.data.pageTitle()` I get undefined...

```
data: {
   pageTitle: function($state) {
      return $state;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use the ***data*** property. You can directly use the params in the controller using $stateParams service.
Ex-

```
$state.go('main.employees', { pageType: 'HR' });            
$state.go('main.employees', { pageType: 'Directors' });
```

And in controller access the params as given below-

console.log($stateParams.pageType)

Comment: You can't: ReferenceError: pageType is not defined

Comment: Okay... So as per your requirement don't need to use data property. You can access the params in the controller directly by using $stateParams

Comment: I do because I'm using this param in a different controller. I can't use $state of a different controller that's a sibling.